# Mule Cloudhub - Service not available for request uri: /*

Tags: cloudhub

I am getting very strange problem where after deploying my plain HTTP application on cloudhub, I am getting response message as :

```
Service not available for request uri: /*
```

The same application works fine when I run it from my local anypoint studio embedded server.

Please could one help or have faced this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using cloudhub url properly?
-Anand